# Reparametrization trick in VAE at Evaluation time

Tags: tensorflow, autoencoders, variational-bayes, generative-models

So I've been trying to implement the Variational Auto-Encoder model of Kigma *et.al,* but something has been bugging me. While I understand the need for reparametrization trick at training time, the rational behind the usage of the same trick at evaluation time is escaping me.

---

At training time we turn the random (latent) variable $z$ into a deterministic function in order to allow gradients to flow through it:

$$= +⋅$$

where $∼N(0,1)$. However, at evaluation time such trick is not required, since we can directly sample the latent variable $$ from the parametric model (encoder network) $(∣,)$ of the true posterior.

Yet, [most](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/vae/main.py)  [implementations](https://github.com/tik0/vae_tools/blob/dev/examples/VAE_toy_examples/jmmVAE_singleStartUp_simple-Final-Copy1.py) [of](https://github.com/hardmaru/WorldModelsExperiments/blob/master/carracing/vae_train.py) [VAE](https://github.com/shaohua0116/VAE-Tensorflow/blob/master/demo.ipynb) I have come across still perform the reparametrization trick at evaluation time.

So my question is "What is the rational behind using the reparametrization trick at testing time?".

Answer (score 2):

> However, at evaluation time such trick is not required, since we can
>   directly sample the latent variable $$ from the parametric model
>   (encoder network) $(∣,)$ of the true posterior.

To nitpick, $q$ is not the true posterior, just an approximation of it.

To answer your question: because it doesn't cost more than not using the trick, and also because now you can reuse code instead of writing the same function in two different ways.